# windows domain in biztalk sftp adapter?

Tags: dns, biztalk, sftp, adapter

im just starting to use a biztalk sftp adapter,
it seems fairly simple, but Im wondering if it can take a windows style domain with the username?

eg

sftp://domain//username@123.45.67.89/sftp_test/test.txt

thanks

DD

Comment: What SFTP adapter are you using?

Comment: nsoftware, trial version until i can prove it works ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to do a dynamic send? I don't know if you can put the domain that way in the URI for the nsoftware adapter, but you'd probably be able to specify the username and password using the corresponding context properties instead, if that works for you.